# Call global variable array() in woocommerce child/template

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, array, variables, globals

So I have this in my functions file - it defines the products that are not eligible for free shipping. It works everything is fine.

```
//functions.php
function my_free_shipping( $is_available ) {
global $woocommerce;

// set the product ids that are $product_notfree_ship
$product_notfree_ship = array( '1', '2', '3', '4', '5' );

// get cart contents
$cart_items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();

// loop through the items looking for one in the ineligible array
foreach ( $cart_items as $key => $item ) {
    if( in_array( $item['product_id'], $product_notfree_ship ) ) {
        return false;
    }
}

// nothing found return the default value
return $is_available;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_free_shipping_is_available',    'my_free_shipping', 20 );
```

All of the product ID's that I have entered into the array `$product_notfree_ship` are denied free shipping.

Now I want to call those product IDs on the product pages to check and see if they should receive a "Free shipping applies" message or an "Additional shipping charge applies"

so in my theme/woocommerce/single-product/product-image.php (I want it after the main img) file I have

```
//theme/woocommerce/single-product/template.php
$product_notfree_ship = array( '1', '2', '3', '4', '5' );
// this is commented because it didn't work, 
// global $product_notfree_ship;

if ( is_single($product_notfree_ship) ) {
 echo 'Additional Shipping Charges Apply';
} else {
    echo 'FREE SHIPPING on This Product';
}
```

Now, this is working, it just feels stupid to have to edit both arrays, in the event that a new product id needs to be added to the "Not-free-shipping-product-array"

So based on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12638734/how-do-i-declare-a-global-variable-in-php-i-can-use-across-templates)

I thought if called `global $product_notfree_ship;`  before the `if` the proper code would run, however it did not.

Is this because I am using `is_single()` ? 
Is this because its an array and it needs to be called differently?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is all fine. You just need to declare variable global first then you can set the value of this and access globally.

```
function my_free_shipping( $is_available ) {
global $woocommerce, $product_notfree_ship;

// set the product ids that are $product_notfree_ship
$product_notfree_ship = array( '1', '2', '3', '4', '5' );
```

Then again declare it globally when using again in another file

```
global $product_notfree_ship;

if ( is_single($product_notfree_ship) ) {
 echo 'Additional Shipping Charges Apply';
} else {
    echo 'FREE SHIPPING on This Product';
}
```

This is how global variable works.

Answer (score 0):

Declare it as

```
global $product_notfree_ship
```

as you are doing, just access it via this

```
$GLOBALS['product_notfree_ship'];
```